# Elasticsearch combine term and match

Tags: elasticsearch

i have index with two field, code and desc in index `list` in elasticsearch

```
{
 {
  _id : 1,
  code : '123ABC',
  desc : '123-ABC'
 },
 {
  _id : 2,
  code : '123DEF',
  desc : '123-DEF'
 },
}
```

now, i want use search with condition:

- use `term` between code and desc
- if match with code or desc, not use `match`
- if not match with code or desc, use `match` between code and desc

so the result exactly one if keyword is exactly same with code or desc, and show other result if keyword not same with code or desc.
if i using keyword '123' it will show id 1 and 2
else if i using keywoed '123ABC' it will show id 1
else if i using keywoed '123-DEF' it will show id 2

please help. Thanks

i tried using
query
bool
should
term code.keyword
term desc.keyword
match code
match desc

but it doesnt show result what i wanted